# '__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array' Error when having a collectionView in a TableView Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm retrieving JSON data to populate a tableView and an embedded collectionView within the tableView. I'm pretty sure this error is happening because I am hardcoding the tableView rows where the collectionViews are present.

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    switch section {
    case 0: return bannerArray.count
    case 1: return overViewArray.count
    case 2: return 1                           //CollectionView Here
    case 3: return detailsArray.count
    case 4: return socialArray.count
    case 5: return 1                          //CollectionView Here
    case 6: return exploreArray.count
    default: fatalError("Unknown Selection")
    }
  }
```

I'm guessing in these error situations the JSON data being returned for the collectionViews is probably empty or nil. The problem is I only want one row where there is a collectionView present because the number of items in the collectionView could be very high so a collectionViewArray.count for numberOfRowsInSection won't work. Is there any workaround for this where the app doesn't crash like putting an "N/A" in place of the collectionView when it returns empty?

Comment: You could do `return min(1, collectionViewArray.count)`

Comment: I just tried that, I still get the same error.

Comment: He meant `max(1, collectionViewArray.count)` which will return `1` if there are some items and `0` if there aren't any items. You can also check the number of items in `cellForIndex` method and instead of indexing put some placeholder data there.